# How to go to home menu when home button is clicked on tablet or mobile?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed a app but when I click on Home button in the tablet or android mobile(not back  button) it behaves like back button only. I have many activity's in my app.How I can rectify this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: And you did not override the home button?

Comment: You can override onKeyDown event (if you havent) check if the current KeyEvent is KEYCODE_HOME if so, fire an intent to go to the home screen. A quick google will help you. I can't remember what the intent is from memory. If you have overriden the home key event, thats probably why it wont work as intended.

Comment: #Joey Roosing: Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't call finish() for the current activity,

so, whenever you call the another Activity by Intent class you should finish the current activity like

CurrentActivityClass.finish();

before calling another activity class for navigation.

Comment: Generally, you use the back button to go back to the previous activity. Home you use to go to the home screen regardless of activities being destroyed. What you are doing is making sure the current activty is the only one alive. This is usually not how you want to do things.